# What is the difference between web design and front-end development?

Tags: website-design, frontend-development

They *seem* to both imply the skill-set of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: If you see these terms as job titles, then you really have to ask them what they meant with these because they are rarely used in the strict, textbook definitions. People whose titles are Web Designer role are often asked to code while Front-end Developers are also often asked to design. It varies widely from place to place.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about user experience.

Answer (score 20):

If I were to diagram the range of skills each has:

```
<-- Art & Design                                          Computer Science -->

| ------------- Web Designer ------------|
                 | --------- Front End Developer ---------|
                                     | --------- Back End Developer ---------|
```

That, of course, is just a general range as specific skill sets can vary wildly, but, in general "web designers" lean towards visual/UI design and FED's lean towards JS/CSS/HTML. Sometimes they don't overlap skill sets at all. Ideally, though, they overlap skill sets a lot.

Comment: plus one for diagram

Answer (score 4):

Both of these terms are an unfortunate by-product of the industry's preoccupation with rigid role separation.  In the most general sense, a web designer is a designer who designs for the web environment, whereas a front-end developer develops primarily for the client-side portion of the web environment (the browser).

Realistically, a web designer is the role of someone who formulates solutions to problems specific to the web environment based (hopefully) on an understanding of the higher-level limitations of that environment, without necessarily being able to implement the solution at the technical/development level.

On that note, what used to be the fairly easy to define role of front-end development has changed drastically due to the fast-growing overlap between client/server functionality.  A front-end developer no longer *just* cuts up graphic assets or *just* writes CSS because the behavioral layer of the server environment has become much more dependent on the behavioral layer of the client side(think *node.js, meteor.js, handlebars, requirejs, ember.js*).

Further, due to the technical knowledge that may be beyond the realm of the designer, the front-end developer typically has a hand in the conceptual phase of design.  Ironically, positions advertised as 'web developer/designer' are probably the closest to describing the true responsibilities of both roles, whilst also serving as a red flag to many potential candidates that an employer doesn't really know what they need.

So the short answer is there's no short answer.  These definitions are more of an industry convenience than semantically useful descriptors.

Answer (score 2):

Design doesn't mean you have to code.  In fact, a lot of designers would be rather offended if you asked them to code.

Software **design involves a lot of user research** to figure out how people are actually going to interact with the software, whereas front-end **development codes** the interface.  Sometimes, one person will do both jobs, but this can be problematic because it means that the software model (how the engineers think about the code) will be the same as the model presented in the interface, whereas the interface model really ought to be the same as the *user's* mental model.

Think of a car.  The engineer could make the car turn right when the user pulls a rudder left, but that would be counterintuitive for many users, even if it did align with the engineer's mental model of how the car works.  To make the design work for users, it's necessary to have someone figuring out how users deal with it.  That person is the designer.

Comment: I agree, though note that the issue isn't so much that one person may do both, but only if that one person doesn't have the ability to think like each role. In otherwords, an engineer that thinks the Linux command line would likely create a pretty poor UI if tasked with design. However, I've also met engineers that were really great designers too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit irritated by the previous posts suggesting that the two 'occupations' could actually be easily put into either or box – overlapping in some tasks and skills. I would rather suggest that this is not the case.

I have the impression that both terms are constantly under construction – beeing defined and re-defined by people that work in that field by using those terms for this or that purpose: either to define their own job, to describe their own set of skills, or to draw a line between different tasks, etc. (maybe something like "*Sorry, I'm not coding, I'm the web designer – you'll have to ask the front-end developer*" sounds familiar).

So to come back to your question: personally I would suggest "web design" would imply tasks and skills that are more design focussed (might even include Photoshopping, Wireframing, etc.) and "front-end development" would imply tasks and skills that are more tec focussed (might include JavaScripting, but also Cookie-handling etc.). But on the other hand I do also know people that call themselves  "front-end developer" and all they do is draw boxes and arrows –– and I also know "web designers" that are doing drawing-by-numbers mostly coding in jQuery, CSS etc.

Well - did my answer answer anything? Now I have the feeling it did just raise more questions. Sorry for that, but maybe those questions are part of the answer.

PS: inspired by DA01 I just added this -->

```
<-- Art & Design                                         Computer Science -->
| ------------- Web Designer ------- - - - ------ Web Developer ------------|
| --------- Front End Developer ---- - - - ---- Back End Developer ---------|
```

Answer (score 1):

The words that you used in the question provides the answer. Wed design has more focus on the designing aspect of the task, where as front-end development deals more with the implementation side of the task. Of course, there are overlapping skill sets between the two roles (e.g. CSS, HTML, Javascript), and in many cases the two jobs are done by the same person in the company. I would say that in general front-end developers are more concerned with implementing the design as per the specification, whereas in web design you are the one that has to provide the specs and some of the visual assets for the front-end developer to use.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a very thoughtful and, I think, accurate description of job titles in the industry: http://css-tricks.com/job-titles-in-the-web-industry/

**EDIT**

Web design is literally the designing the look and feel a of a site/webapp. This may include some html/css/javascript.

Front End Development would not include designing the look and feel of the site at all, but a thorough knowledge of front end technologies html/css/javascript and how it hooks into the back end.

Comment: [Link only answers are generally frowned upon on this site.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).  Perhaps you could update your post to include a summary of that article?

Comment: I would not say 'web design' is literally anything. In the end, it's a job title, and skill sets per title vary wildly--especially in this industry. I've seen FED's that are expected to create the visual design and Web Designers that are expected to create all the AJAX calls.